# Having a problem populating a Dts Variable

Tags: c#, ssis

I have an SSIS package that is using a script task within a data flow task that should be populating a package level variable with a string value.  Stepping through the code shows that the variable is populating but once the script has finished, there is no value in the variable.  Any ideas?

I've tried populating the variable via the Post Execute method.

The variable is defined at package level:
Name: bksbCreatedId
Scope: CreateSingleAccount
Data Type: String
Value:

The Script task has the variable specified in the ReadWrite Variables option:
User::bksbCreatedId

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters
    #region Help:  Using Integration Services Connnection Managers
    #region Help:  Firing Integration Services Events

  private string _currentBKSBId;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();

        _currentBKSBId = "";
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Current processing BKSB In Post Execute: {0}", _currentBKSBId)); // <-- returns 64964081
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Current processing BKSB In Post Execute (Actual Variable - before populattion): {0}", Variables.bksbCreatedId)); // <-- returns empty string

        Variables.bksbCreatedId = _currentBKSBId;

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Current processing BKSB In Post Execute (Actual Variable - after population): {0}", Variables.bksbCreatedId)); // <-- returns 64964081
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        _currentBKSBId = Row.bksbUserId.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Current processing BKSB In Process Row: {0}", _currentBKSBId));  // <-- returns 64964081

    }

}
```

Prior to calling the script the value of Row.bksbUserId is "64964081".  This is what I expect the User::bksbCreatedId to be once the task has completed, so that the value can be used in another script task in a separate data control task.  However, when inspecting the variable on the Post-Excecute breakpoint of the script task, and the Pre-Execute breakpoint on the next Script task, the value is never populated and the variable remains empty.

There are no errors occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you're running into is the confusion over the Variables and the Variables.

The first "Variables" window is your design-time set of things so you've created a variable bksbCreatedId of type String at the package level. If you initialize it with a value of "BillInKC is the greatest", when your data flow completes, the value of the Variable in the variable window will still read "BillInKC is the greatest." Because that's the design time value.

To simplify your problem, here is a package that uses the Expression Task to change the design time value of this variable at runtime to ABC

[image: Control flow with Expression Task and a container set as breakpoint]

The run-time value is visible through the Locals window (Debug menu). If I expand Variables there, I see my User::bksbCreatedId and it reads ABC as expected. The right pane shows Variables and it still has the value of "BillInKC is the greatest" but again, that's the design-time value. Ignore that when the package is running. You want to inspect the values in the Variables collection available in the Locals windows.

[image: Locals = run-time value. Variables = design-time values]

Locals = run-time value. Variables = design-time values

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I understand the difference between run-time and design-time variables.  I should have posted originally that I was inspecting the variable at run-time through the locals (well Watch as for some reason I can't get variables in the locals window to show the variables - it shows Variables in the locals window but when I click the arrow point to expand the list it shows nothing, even though I have a number of variables that it could show).

Comment: Oh good, something more complex than "the usual." Just to confirm, when the successor script actually fires, the value for this Variable remains empty? It's not just a timing situation with the pre-execute event firing before the DFT has finished the post execute activities?

Comment: Yes, I think it is a timing issue.  I rebuilt a test package to simulate the same process.  I now get visibility of the variables at run time through locals, but I still get the same issue with updating the value.  I'm going to add in some debug comments to determine when things are firing.